# How to add new row in handsontable angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, handsontable

I am using handsonetable with angularjs and I want to add a new row by clicking an add button.
Is it possible to create dynamic rows in Handsontable grid? and how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I've use following code in my project is work well.

```
<label>Filter:
<input type="text" ng-model="query">
</label>
<hot-table datarows="results|filter:query">
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at ngHandsontable? That will make it easy, you can configure it to use a model on the scope for rows, and handsontable will take care of the rest.

https://github.com/handsontable/ngHandsontable

Comment: Yes, I am using ngHandsometable and trying to add new row using alter method. But its not working.

Comment: You shouldn't need to call into HOT directly for this. If it's initialised with `<hot-table datarows="items" />` then you can just manipulate `$scope.items` and ngHandsontable will update the table accordingly.

Comment: Actually I am having bootstrap modal popup and trying to add checked values into ngHandsontable row. So is it possible through  $scope.items?

Comment: As long as you are updating `items` on the same scope your handsontable is on, it should work. This would involve a promise, a callback or a shared service to work with the angular UI modal.